# Quelle est l'onomatopée du « bâillement » ?

Tags: onomatopées

Quelle est l'[onomatopée](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Cat%C3%A9gorie:Onomatop%C3%A9es_en_fran%C3%A7ais) du [*bâillement*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ba%C3%AEllement) (de [*bâiller*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ba%C3%AEller/1) « ouvrir involontairement la bouche en inspirant profondément et en contractant les muscles du visage », TLFi) ? J'ai identifié « [haaaa](http://www.les-onomatopees.fr/onomatopees-corps-humain.php) » avec 4 « a » ; est-elle adéquate et y en a-t-il d'autres ? Généralement, quel est le procédé pour « étirer la longueur » de cette (d'une) onomatopée, quand quelqu'un bâille plus longuement par exemple : sa répétition ou l'ajout d'une lettre (comme le « a » ici) ? Peut-on produire un extrait d'une œuvre qui illustre l'onomatopée ou son « allongement » ?

Answer (score 1):

Il ne semble pas exister d'onomatopée qui soit très caractéristique :  dans les listes courantes on n'en trouve pas, mais il en existe deux attestées dans le TLFi ; la seconde correspondrait à la version longue. Cependant, elles sont ambivalentes puisqu'elles servent pour certains sons exprimant la douleur aussi bien que pour le bâillement.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ahouahou))     AHOU, AHOUAHOU, interj.
> Exclamation de douleur ou onomatopée imitant le bâillement, l'aboiement
> ♦ Tout à coup un long et bruyant bâillement se fait entendre venant de la pièce du fond. La voix. − ahouahouahahah! G. Feydeau, La Dame de chez Maxim's,1914, I, IV, p. 8.